# System of equations problem.

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

Which method is much easier to determine the solution of these two system of equations?

1) $y = \frac{7}{5x} - 9$

2) $4y = 3x + 3$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have the system

$$ A_1 x + B_1 y = C_1 $$
$$ A_2 x + B_2 y = C_2 $$

where $A_i,B_i,C_i \in \mathbb{R}$ where they are not multiples of each other: 
We have two lines in the plane. To solve this system of equations is equivalent to ask where these two lines meet: Lets find it. Write the lines as follows:

$$ y = \frac{C_1 - A_1 x}{B_1} $$

$$ y = \frac{C_2 - A_2 x}{B_2} $$

And so

$$ \frac{C_1 - A_1 x}{B_1} = \frac{C_2 - A_2 x}{B_2} \iff \frac{C_1}{B_1} - \frac{C_2}{B_2} = \frac{A_1}{B_1}x - \frac{A_2}{B_2}x \iff x = \frac{\frac{C_1}{B_1} - \frac{C_2}{B_2}}{\frac{A_1}{B_1} - \frac{A_2}{B_2}}$$

after substitution,

$$ y = \frac{C_2 - A_2\left( \frac{\frac{C_1}{B_1} - \frac{C_2}{B_2}}{\frac{A_1}{B_1} - \frac{A_2}{B_2}}\right)}{B_2}$$

Comment: a little bit more complicated than required, but this sure makes this question a piece of cake. Good work